# Sent emails don't appear in Sent folder

Tags: mail.app, email

I have a curious problem, that started recently with no obvious trigger or change in any configurations, that I know of, that might have triggered the problem.

In Apple Mail, my "Sent" folder will now only show a single email with the "Date Sent" field as "Today".  Additionally, it appears to only show my most recent email as the single email.

It does show emails from earlier dates, but a real gap in time from the single "Today" email.

As of this post on 29 Nov 2016, I have a single email showing "Today", them other Sent email on 24 Nov 2015 (5 days of emails missing).  Not certain without doing some forensics, but I think other Sent emails look missing from each date as well.

Interestingly, if I can remember the right search criteria (like entering "Today" in the Search box) the hidden emails found by the search appear.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

---

A possible new/additional clue:

[image]

In my "Account Info" window shown above, I see two emails apparently received this morning (30 Nov 2016) From "Sender Unknown". (Note, I've had to cover the names on other emails).

These emails do not appear in my Inbox.

Not certain if this means anything or not.
Please advise.

Comment: have you tried [rebuilding your mailboxes](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22339?locale=en_US)?

Comment: @victor -- trying to rebuild now, but the way all the emails disappear does not give one a sense of comfort.  Any idea how long it takes?

Comment: @victor -- that seems to have solved most of the problem. -- Thx

Comment: is there still a problem after the rebuild?

Comment: @victor Everything looks OK now.  Even the "Sender Unkown" messages have disappeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you encounter a problem with `Mail.app`, the first step is to [rebuild](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22339?locale=en_US) culprit mailboxes.

> When you rebuild mailboxes for IMAP or Exchange accounts, messages and attachments stored on your computer are discarded, and then downloaded again from the mail server to your Mac. Your mailbox appears empty until the download is complete.

It is a similar fix to clearing your browser cache when you encounter website problems.

Comment: Sad to say the problem has returned.